# CDN fallback on Webpack 2 async code spliting

Tags: webpack, cdn, webpack-2, code-splitting

### Is there any way to config fallback of async chunk on webpack 2?

This is what I want to have:

- Fail to load http://cdn.example.com/chunk-1.js -> load http://another-cdn.example.com/chunk-1.js
- Fail to load http://another-cdn.example.com/chunk-1.js -> load http://www.example.com/chunk-1.js

Like feature provided by [Fallback JS](http://fallback.io/)

`` // Include `jQuery`.
"jQuery": {
    // The URLs to load `jQuery`.
    "urls": [
        "//.....some-bad-cdn...../.....FAIL-ON-PURPOSE.....",
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min",
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min"
    ]
}, ``

I have read the [Code Splitting - Async](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/) documentation. There is no related options.

The closet way I got to the solution is to fire another jsonp request to a new url inside the [require.ensure error callback](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#error-callback), but I cannot get the chunk url from the error event.

======== Update on 12 June ========

Got some [progress](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5021) on this problem, but there is another road block.
The public path can be changed dynamically, but I need to inject the code in webpack runtime code in manifest.js (generated by common chunk plugin).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @MattWhetton
I didn't implement the fix, but I build an dirty POC and seems it is working